# PHP update won't properly update database

Tags: php, jquery, mysql, ajax

The following code is part of my ajax notification system and for some reason, it is working only 50%. When I call the code, it runs and then echo's either `success` or `remove` but it doesn't seem to change the database values. Any reason? I have tried putting my column names in quotes but that echo's an error. Please help, thanks!

```
<?php
require_once('.conf.php');
$notid = mysql_real_escape_string($_GET['notification_id']);
$username = mysql_real_escape_string($_SESSION['uname']);
$action = mysql_real_escape_string($_GET['action']);

if ($action == 'add') {
    $insert = mysql_query("UPDATE updates SET object_fav = '1' WHERE username = '$username' AND id = '$notid'") or die('Could not connect: ' . mysql_error());
    echo 'success';
} elseif($action == 'sub') {
    $remove = mysql_query("UPDATE updates SET object_fav = '0' WHERE username = '$username' AND id = '$notid'") or die('Could not connect: ' . mysql_error());
    echo 'remove';
} else {
    echo 'error';
}
?>
```

---

I know it is not the javascript, I have checked the network tab and it is sending the correct values.

Comment: Well, your `die()` calls would have fired if the query errored out.  `echo mysql_affected_rows();` along with `success/remove`. More likely, you just aren't matching any rows because `$username` or `$notid` doesn't contain what you expect it to

Comment: @michael Yeah higher above in the php

Comment: Hmm, turns out that I uploaded the wrong version of this that didn't include `session_start()`. Stupid me... You were right michael

Comment: Ok, I undeleted my answer about `session_start()` then :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If this is the start of the script, you have not called `session_start()`, and therefore `$_SESSION['uname']` will contain an empty value.  The query succeeds because it is syntactically correct, but doesn't match any rows and therefore performs no update.

```
session_start();
require_once('.conf.php');
$notid = mysql_real_escape_string($_GET['notification_id']);
$username = mysql_real_escape_string($_SESSION['uname']);
$action = mysql_real_escape_string($_GET['action']);
```

Answer (score 0):

Echo $insert and $remove and find which values are missing.

Comment: `$insert` and `$remove` contain booleans as the return of `mysql_query()`, not strings.